# .class file stopped getting generated suddenly in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, selenium

I am working on an automation project where I automate manual processes of general insurance sector using `JAVA` and `SELENIUM WEBDRIVER`. I have created a java project in eclipse. Inside it under src I created a single package containing 6 .java files.

I wrote 90% of the code and tested all the files. They were running properly and showing the automated output. One day I appended some lines of code to a java file. It was called from main method class where main method class suddenly started showing error under the name of that class. Firstly it said to import the class which itself was in the same package of main class. Secondly even after clicking on importing command of the class the error did not went away.

Lastly I cleaned the project in eclipse and the error went away but when I tried to run the project then it gave the error as `NoClassDefFoundError` and `ClassNotFoundException`. I checked the bin folder inside the project folder on drive. There .class file for the error class was missing while other classes .class file was present. Everytime I make changes in the main method class and save it eclipse starts showing error under that class name. The error goes when I clean the project. It is a repetitive occurrence in eclipse.

Code for all java classes without main method are 99% same still error is coming for one java class only while other java classes are running fine with almost the same lines of code

Can anyone please explain me the reason behind such behaviour of java compiler in eclipse. Its really a strange show of java `compiler` the reason behind which I am not able to understand. Please do let me know about the reason behind this act of JAVA compiler in eclipse as I am very curious to know the reason for it. I use jdk 1.8 and selenium standalone server ver 3.0.1

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: Clean the project. If it doesn't work close and restart eclipse or else build folder in the workplace

Comment: I have cleaned the project many times. As written above whenever I clean the project error markup goes but I am still not able to run the class by calling it from main class. Eclipse still gives the same error of NoClassDefFoundError and ClassNotFoundException because .class file is not present in bin folder of eclipse. I have also restarted the eclipse, created a new project, changed the workshop also but no effect from any of these attempts.

Comment: Try to check on build project on automatically in Project tab and also use ctrl+shift+tab and check whether class is available in the classpath or not.

Comment: Automatically build project was checked by default from starting. No use of it thus in .class file generation. Also nothing happens with ctrl+shift+tab in eclipse and what do you mean exactly by "class is available in the classpath or not". Problem is solved by now through some way but I am curious to know the reason behind eclipse automatically deleting the .class file of a single class from a project and not generating it again on multiple compilations.

Comment: It may be a bug in the version of the eclipse you are using..I faced this issue while using indigo.

Comment: Oh is it so. I was using Luna version of eclipse. Well thanks for your answer to solve my query.